# Pass logging level as variable to python3 code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, settings

Here is my code:

```
import logging
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")

def setup_logger(name, log_file, level=logging.INFO):
    # To setup as many loggers as you want

    handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)        
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(level)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    return logger

# Application Log:

app_log = setup_logger("app", "app.log", logging.DEBUG)

# Usage Log:

usage_log = setup_logger("usage", "usage.log", logging.DEBUG)
```

I want to pass the `logging.DEBUG` level as variable from `settings.ini` file.

Please instruct me how can I pass it as variable?

Should I do this as string `"logging.INFO"` or there is any other method?

Comment: I didn't get it. Do you need to define a log level or call debug level (the type) dynamically? Python's default behavior is print the log only when the level is "warning" or higher, in a scale of severity. This can be set by "setLevelName". Otherwise, when you use logging.DEBUG or logging.INFO and so on, if you want set the level (DEBUG, INFO, etc.) through a variable, I don't know how you can do it and it is what I am looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a variable while calling logger.setLevel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332748/using-a-variable-while-calling-logger-setlevel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution and sharing with others:

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332748/using-a-variable-while-calling-logger-setlevel) source's code:

```
Log = logging.getLogger('myLogger')
level = logging.getLevelName('INFO')
Log.setLevel(level)
```

I have set in my settings.ini file the log level I want:

```
[Logging]
log_level = DEBUG
```

And modified the code:

```
# Read settings.ini file

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(dir_path + "/settings.ini")

# Logging

formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")

log_level = config.get("Logging", "log_level")

def setup_logger(name, log_file, level_name = 'INFO'):
    # To setup as many loggers as you want

    handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)        
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    level = logging.getLevelName(level_name)
    logger.setLevel(level)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    return logger

# Application Log:

app_log = setup_logger("app", "app.log", log_level)

# Usage Log:

usage_log = setup_logger("usage", "usage.log", log_level)
```

Comment: And also this source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48787538/how-to-set-logging-level-for-the-module-only-in-python